# Reuseable blocks inside of custom form themes in symfony

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-forms

I want to call a custom block inside an overwritten theme-block:

```
{% block file_widget %}
    {% if image is not null %}
        {{ block('imagePreview') }}
    {% endif %}

    {{ block('form_widget') }}
{% endblock %}

{% block imagePreview %}
    <img src="{{ image.getFullPath | imagine_filter('medium_square') }}"
         alt="{{ image.filename }}"/>
{% endblock %}
```

The `imagePreview` is not shown.
But it is working when I don't use a block.
And it is also working when I dont use a FormTypeExtension and create an ImageType instead.

So I guess the `file_widget`block still has the scope of the parent `form_div_layout.html.twig` and there in fact no `imagePreview` block exists.

So how can I solve this.

I mean now I solved it by removing the block.

But I just want to know if someone has a solution to this.
Maybe there is a way for using reuseable blocks inside of custom form themes in symfony?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution:

I just did not 'use' the base template explicit.
The form theme worked without this - because symfony falls back the the base form theme when it does not find a block inside the new theme file.

But it seems then you also can not use custom blocks inside this new theme file.

So this works now:

```
{% use 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block file_widget %}
    {% if image is not null %}
        {{ block('imagePreview') }}
    {% endif %}

    {{ block('form_widget') }}
{% endblock %}

{% block imagePreview %}
    <img src="{{ image.getFullPath | imagine_filter('medium_square') }}"
         alt="{{ image.filename }}"/>
{% endblock %}
```